# properties of left-invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

When reading the notes on Left-invertible matrix, where $A$ is a matrix of dimension of $m\times n$, and $X A=I$. It is claimed that it $m$ must be larger than $n$, and $rank(A)=n$.How to get these two properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A were left-invertible and $m<n$, then $n>m\ge rank(A)\ge rank(XA)=rank(I)=n$ which is a contradiction. If $m$ is indeed greater or equal to $n$, then the part of the above inequality chain that is still valid shows, that $rank(A)\ge n$, but on the other hand the rank is smaller or equal to the number of collumns, hence $rank(A)\le n$ and therefore $rank(A)=n$